# Maximum and Minimum Values of the function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

What will be the maximum and minimum value of the following function,

$f(x,y)=3x+4y$ in the region $0\le x \le1$, $-1\le y \le1 $

Comment: Your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way to consider this (and it doesn't even use calculus), which touches on what **cooper.hat** describes.

Consider that the equation $ \ 3x + 4y \ = C \ $ represents a "family" of parallel lines, shifting "upward and to the right" as $ \ C \ $ increases.  (This is a bit clearer if we write the equation in "slope-intercept" form as  $ \ y = \frac{C}{4} - \frac{3}{4}x \ . $ ) The region you are interested in is a rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes.  So as we follow these lines in the "direction of increasing C", there is a line which just makes contact with the "lower left" vertex of the rectangle, $ \ ( 0, -1 ) \ $ .  The value of $ \ C \ $ for that line is $ \ 3 \cdot 0 \ + \ 4 \cdot (-1) \ = \ -4 \ , $ so this is the minimum value of our function for this region.

As we continue, successive lines pass through the perimeter and interior of the rectangle, until we reach a line which makes "final contact" with the rectangle at its "upper right" vertex, $ \ ( 1 , 1 ) \ . $  There, the value of $ \ C \ $ is $ \ 3 \cdot 1 \ + \ 4 \cdot 1 \ = \ 7 \ , $ the maximum value of our function for the region.

More sophisticated methods would show more directly that we should not expect the extremes for the function to occur in the interior of the rectangle, leaving us to check the sides and then the vertices.  For a (bi)linear function such as the one in this problem and regions like rectangles, we can jump immediately to testing the values at the vertices.

Answer (score 1):

$\max_{x,y} f(x,y) = \max_x \max_y f(x,y)$, where $x \in [0,1], y \in [-1,1]$, and similarly for $\min$.

For example, $\max_y f(x,y) = f(x,1) = 3x+4$, and $\max_x (3x+4) = 3+4 = 7$.